# How do I get rid of these excess goat corpses around my Science Hole?

Tags: goat-simulator

Okay, so I may have abused my demonic powers a bit:

[image: too many corpses, baaaaa]

I was trying to increase my combo by adding some targets that I could lick or headbutt between aerial tricks.  However, it seems to have backfired.  There's this massive pile of goat corpses littering the area.  Every time I rotate the camera towards my Science Hole, the whole game lags for several seconds and the frame rate drops to the single digits.

I don't really want to start over, as I still need to score some points and moving to a new area resets my points total.

Is there any way I can clear these dead goats out of the way?  I tried the goat equivalent of the fus ro dah (baa ro baaaaa?) but then they just clogged up the Science Hole and erupted in random directions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try sacrificing a few goats to Satan behind the party near the Goat Protest.  You'll have plenty if you've got the power to summon infinite goats.

If you haven't got that power, humans will have to do. Attack a few party-goers to knock them down, then lick them and drag them up the mountain onto a large glowing satanic symbol.  You can't miss it.

You'll need five sacrifices in total before you unlock demonic powers.  You'll be able to summon a black hole with Satan's power, and with that black hole, you should be able to gather all the goats together into one goat singularity, and then carry that singularity elsewhere on the map.

I recommend hiding your goat bodies under the water slide.

### Update:

Summoning goats for sacrifice no longer works.  You must lick and drag all 5 party-goers to the ritual site to unlock your satanic powers.

Comment: This has to be a joke answer, right? If not, this game is far more interesting than I thought.

Comment: @user1853181 This is a 100% accurate answer.  Though I think I should edit it to include the proper sacrificial methods in-game.  And yes, I am serious, this is really in the game and works.

Comment: That's a surprisingly deep mechanic for a game called _goat simulator_. I'm in awe.